# Dot Net Nuke - Sub Domains

Tags: iis-7, dns, dotnetnuke

I've got a DNN portal set up for me and my brother, which works, and i'd like to make it so that sub domains point to our respective sub section of the sites. I.e.

brothers.co.uk = brothers.co.uk/home.aspx

me.brothers.co.uk = brothers.co.uk/me.aspx

him.brothers.co.uk = brothers.co.uk/him.aspx

I've got the sub sections set up in DNN, but can't figure out what to do with domain names to get it working. I'd like this to be all one site with the same login set, although if there's a better way to structure this, I'm open to ideas.

Any thoughts?

Regards

Tristan

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a slightly different solution. Create two portals, one for you and one for your brother. You'll then be able to associate each of the portals to their own unique URL by setting the portal alias for yours to me.brothers.co.uk and his to him.brothers.co.uk. You can manage the portals for your DotNetNuke instance from the Host -> Portals page, when logged in as a super user (host).

The portals themselves can be as simple or as complex as you'd like, but a good rule of thumb is that if the sites are different enough to have different top level URLs, they are different enough to be unique portals.

Answer (score 0):

The set up can be done in IIS.  Add those sub-domains to IIS as websites, then add a permanent redirect to the correct url.